# ENUM column auto set

Tags: mysql, enum

I have two tables "using" foreign keys:

1. Referencing table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `requests` (
   `request_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   --       
   `status` enum('new','approved') DEFAULT NULL,
   --       ^^^^
   PRIMARY KEY (`request_id`),
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
   ```
2. Referenced table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `status` (
   `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `status_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`status_id`),
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
   ```

Now, I want something like this, If I create a new row, say, 'pending' name in the `status` table then `status` (list of ENUM values) of `requests` table automatically updated with 'pending' ENUM value. So, the "final" `status` allowed ENUM values in the `request` table would be:

- `status('new','approved','Pending')`

Answer (score 1):

Change the status table to match

```
  CREATE TABLE `status` (
  `status` enum('new','approved') DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`status`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

There is no need for `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Then do this for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE ...
  MODIFY COLUMN `status` enum('new','approved','Pending') DEFAULT NULL;
```

Be sure to change all references to `status_id`.